# no animation when connected to the MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, jsp

I am trying to move an object in html5 canvas based on the location of x and y axis retrieved from the MySQL database. The code was working when I did it without the database. But after connecting the page to the database, there is no movement.

Please tell me where am I going wrong. Or is there any other way of doing it.

Please do no suggest switching to PHP.

index.jsp

```
<%@page center code here`ontentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
       #canvas{
           border: #666 2px solid;
       }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function draw(x,y)
       {
          var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
          var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.save();
          ctx.clearRect(0,0,550,400);
          ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,200,0,1)";
          <%@include file="connectToDB.jsp"%>
          <%
            int a,b;
            String sql="SELECT * FROM movement_details";
            try{
               rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
               while (rs.next()) 
              {
                 a=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(4));
                 b=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(5));
           %>
            var x="<%=a%>";
            var y="<%=b%>";

            ctx.fillRect(x,y,30,30);
            ctx.restore();  

           setTimeout(100);
        <%
             }
          }catch (Exception e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }finally 
          {
              try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         }
         %>
      }

  </script>
</head>

<body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas> 

    <!--<button onclick="draw('x','y');">Draw</button>-->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the file where I connect the page to the database.

connectToDB.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%  String str = " ";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    //out.print(" "+session.getAttribute("empID"));
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2";
    String connectionUser = "root";
    String connectionPassword = "root";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();%>
```

Comment: Does the DB binding work properly? Are there any exceptions in the log?

Comment: @Jozef no there are no exceptions. I also tried printing the values from the DB, and its printing all the values correctly. So no issues in the binding.